# Update array based on other array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of the same size:

```
import numpy as np
myArray = np.array([[5,3,2,1,2],
                    [2,5,3,3,3]])

myotherArray = np.array([[0,1,1,0,0],
                         [0,0,1,0,0]])
```

I like to multiple all values in `myArray` by 5, but only if on the same index in `myotherArray` a value of 0 is. How do I do this?
I tried this, but it doesn't do anything.

```
myArray[myotherArray == 0]*5
```

My expected output is for `myArray`

```
([[25,3,2,5,10],
  [10,25,3,15,15]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply in place:

```
>>> myArray[myotherArray == 0] *= 5
>>> myArray
array([[25,  3,  2,  5, 10],
       [10, 25,  3, 15, 15]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but:

```
>>> myArray * np.where(myotherArray == 0, 5, 1)
array([[25,  3,  2,  5, 10],
       [10, 25,  3, 15, 15]])
```

Another alternative:

```
>>> np.where(myotherArray == 0, 5*myArray, myArray)
array([[25,  3,  2,  5, 10],
       [10, 25,  3, 15, 15]])
```